# Javascript: Parsing xml to get matched tag value within node

Tags: javascript, xml

I am a beginner level javascripter, and have the following problem. I am adding javascript functionality to an assessment form.

The user will choose an item from a dropdown giving me a value which I can grab an stuff in a variable. (so var appetite=2 for example).

I then have an XML document loaded into the DOM as a variable.
What I need to do is to search the XML for the value within matched nodes and grab a paired value to give me a score.

My XML looks like this:-

```
 <root Patient_ID="1333" Current_User="Iain Cowden" Current_Date="05/02/2021" Current_Time="20:15">
  <SQLQuery elementNameInResults="BMI" recordCount="1">select top 1 BMI ,<br/>case when BMI between 20 and 24.9 then 1<br/>when BMI between 25 and 29.9 then 2<br/>when BMI >=30 then 3<br/>when BMI<20 then 0 end as BMI_Score,<br/>case when gv.Gender_ID=2 then 2 <br/>when gv. Gender_ID=3 then 1 end as Gender_Score,<br/>case when dbo.GetAge(Date_Of_Birth,Estimated_Year_Of_Birth,Date_Of_Death) <=49 then 1<br/>when dbo.GetAge(Date_Of_Birth,Estimated_Year_Of_Birth,Date_Of_Death) between 50 and 64 then 2<br/>when dbo.GetAge(Date_Of_Birth,Estimated_Year_Of_Birth,Date_Of_Death) between 65 and 74 then 3<br/>when dbo.GetAge(Date_Of_Birth,Estimated_Year_Of_Birth,Date_Of_Death) between 75 and 80 then 4<br/>when dbo.GetAge(Date_Of_Birth,Estimated_Year_Of_Birth,Date_Of_Death) >80 then 5 end as Age_Score,<br/>dbo.GetAge(Date_Of_Birth,Estimated_Year_Of_Birth,Date_Of_Death) as Age,<br/>gv.Gender_Desc as Gender<br/><br/>from tblCHTHealthNoteMeasure nm<br/>join tblpatient p on p.Patient_ID=nm.Patient_ID<br/>join tblgendervalues gv on p.gender_id=gv.gender_id<br/>where nm.Patient_ID=@patientID order by Health_Note_Date desc<SqlParameter name="@patientID" value="1333" type=""></SqlParameter></SQLQuery>
  <BMI>
    <BMI>35.2</BMI>
    <BMI_Score>3</BMI_Score>
    <Gender_Score>1</Gender_Score>
    <Age_Score>4</Age_Score>
    <Age>80</Age>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
  </BMI>
  <SQLQuery elementNameInResults="WLAppetiteID" recordCount="4">select UDP_WLAppetite_ID as WLAppetiteID, External_Code1 as WLAppetite from udpWLAppetiteValues where @patientID=@patientID<SqlParameter name="@patientID" value="1333" type=""></SqlParameter></SQLQuery>
  <WLAppetiteID>
    <WLAppetiteID>0</WLAppetiteID>
    <WLAppetite>0</WLAppetite>
  </WLAppetiteID>
  <WLAppetiteID>
    <WLAppetiteID>1</WLAppetiteID>
    <WLAppetite>2</WLAppetite>
  </WLAppetiteID>
  <WLAppetiteID>
    <WLAppetiteID>2</WLAppetiteID>
    <WLAppetite>3</WLAppetite>
  </WLAppetiteID>
  <WLAppetiteID>
    <WLAppetiteID>3</WLAppetiteID>
    <WLAppetite>5</WLAppetite>
  </WLAppetiteID>
```

I know how to use xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Gender_Score")[0].textContent for example to return the Gender score for the first SQLQuery Nodeset above.

However I can't quite figure out how I can look through the second SQL Query nodeset to find the pair where WLAppetiteID = 2 and then get the value of WLAppetite.

I can't really figure out where to start. GetElementsByTagName just gets me an html collection of all the WLAppetiteID tags regardless of NodeLevel.
I did try using IndexOf or includes on that, but that doesn't seem to be valid.

Any help or pointers deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml in your question is not well formed (for example, it's missing a closing `<root>` tag, but what you are looking for can be done this way:

```
text = `[your xml, fixed]`
let parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
path = ".//WLAppetiteID[.=2]/following-sibling::WLAppetite"
target = xmlDoc.evaluate(path, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
console.log(target.snapshotItem(0).textContent);
```

Output is `3`.

Comment: The XML continues with some other queries that take the same format - I forgot to add the root back in to make it well formed.  I was starting to try to figure out how xpath could be used but I am a long way from your excellent reply!